# Does variable privacy actually have anything to do with security or is it just for programming convenience?

Tags: security, language-agnostic, private, public, protected

For years I have been programming and I think I even understand the difference between public, private and protected for the most part, however are these names simply misleading?  Are these levels of visibility only to help us not trip over our own toes?  Many languages I have programmed do not seem to enforce most of these rules and I've never heard of a hacker breaking into a system because one of your variables was not marked private.

I would love to know this it has been bothering me for many years.

Answer (score 6):

A hacker can access a private variable if they can compute memory offsets correctly. Not too hard.

These access controls cover a broader and generally different class of errors. Better encapsulation simplifies code and makes it easier to reason about, which clears the path for spotting other mistakes which are security problems. (That is, it *indirectly* helps security.)

Code which is harder to break on purpose is probably harder to break by accident, too :-)

Comment: So when I'm declaring things constant and protected and private I'm just making it easier to spot mistakes?  It seems like I'm giving myself extra work and fewer options with those variables.  I usually leave that stuff out if I can and then debug as fast as I can one error at a time.  I just don't know how these words help me.  Seriously I've spent years thinking about this, asking people and now finally asking here.  I can't figure it out.

Comment: Yes you have fewer options with const/private. That's a good thing. There are fewer things to go wrong, fewer things to consider when debugging. If you can attribute a bug to a mutation of private state then you ***massively*** reduce the search space. Make things private/const unless you have to.

Comment: Maybe you should invest some time in declarative/functional languages. You won't return to C++ with the same attitude or style, I guarantee it.

Comment: @user1029030: It's marginal IMO. Programming in Python, which doesn't have those access restrictions, I very rarely spend any time fixing bugs where I've modified something that I shouldn't, or accessed a field that I shouldn't. Not never, but rarely, and I think it's a close-run thing whether all those annotations save time when programming. However, they do often save time when trying to understand the code, which happens when you work in a team or when you return to your own code a couple of years later and have to try to remember which objects are expected to be unmodified.

Comment: @Steve Jessop - Encapsulation moves toward vital when programming in the large and when working with multiple teams. Access control enforces encapsulation.

Comment: @Andy: not in my experience. It's useful, in effect because annotations like "const" and "private" are documentation that the compiler checks are true, and therefore give you more confidence than just a stated requirement "don't modify this" or whatever. But it cannot be true that Python lacks elements that are near-vital for programming in the large, since it has successfully been used in the large, a lot. I like static checks of this kind, and use them when available, but that doesn't make them vital. I make *way* more errors of type in Python than errors of encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks guys it's good to know this is more of a code feature thing and not a security issue thing.  It's always talked about in such an ominous way.  I don't get why everyone is always trying to scare me.  In fact it looks cluttered to me to see all those variable modifiers.  So until someone gives me a really good reason I'm just going to keep making things work.

Comment: Above, @Steve Jessop said _"annotations like "const" and "private" are documentation that the compiler checks are true."_  That's succinct and cogent.  I just wanted it said again in case anyone missed it :)

Answer (score 2):

Access specifiers are a means of ordering source code and not a security feature.

Since the member variables of a class are defined in your own code, they can be accessed in a number of ways(pointers, macros) regardless of the access specifiers.

Comment: Yeah this was one of the other things that always confused me.  If I'm writing all of this code myself why am I bothering to secure things from myself?  I've always used scope to keep my variables in place.

Comment: "Why secure things from myself?" [Experts don't trust themselves.](http://altdevblogaday.com/2011/12/24/static-code-analysis/)

Answer (score 1):

If you create a library for others to use, you want to expose an API and hide everything else. You don't want undocumented "features" all over the place. These can lead to all kinds of bugs, and those in turn can create security holes.

Even if the code isn't for someone else, it's quite easy to forget and trip yourself up by assigning something out of the order that was intended, or thinking a variable means one thing when it means another.

So the short answer is that it's just a programming convenience, but these programming conveniences can help you create more robust and more secure code.

Comment: I can see where you are going with this, but if this is a compiled or hosted API and not a code library then you should be able to scrub all the data coming in to make sure it is not running arbitrary code right?  If it is a library then they can modify it anyway they like anyhow so there isn't much security there...

Comment: There's two different types of "security" here. If it's a compiled or hosted API (non-open source), then you want to keep the code itself safe. Then there's security for the users of the application at all levels, which affects all libraries/APIs/hosted code/whatever. In this case, if someone uses your library and edits it to the detriment of security, that's their fault. Its your job as the original library (compiled or otherwise) developer to make sure it follows good practices as much as possible out of the box.